# Group by sender receiver or receiver sender in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make an inbox section of messages. My problem goes like this.

### id   userfrom   userto

1                         a                      b      
2                        b                      a
now i have to select only one message of conversation between a and b.I have also tried some mysql queries like this one

```
$query="select * 
        from messages 
        where userfrom='a' || userto='a' 
        group by userto 
        order by id desc"
```

but it shows both messages of conversation but i only want to show only one message of the conversation

Comment: This is asked fairly often. Are none of the 'related' questions relevant? And which message do you want to show. Finally, your description and your query suggest two different things. I think there's scope for further clarification here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the following conditional group by query:

```
select * 
from messeages 
where userfrom='a' OR userto='a' 
group by IF(userfrom > userto, userfrom,userto),
         IF(userfrom > userto, userto,userfrom)
order by id desc
```

<kbd>[**WORKING DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16d722/2/0)</kbd>

**Note:** Actually in the `GROUP BY` clause the group by is done based on the following logic:

`GROUP BY greater value of (userfrom,userto), lower value of(userfrom,userto)`

**Example:**

```
userfrom ='a' and userto='b' 

userfrom ='b' and userto='a'
```

In the above two rows greater value is 'b' and lower value is 'a.Thus from both rows `GROUP BY` will be applied first on `b` then on `a`.

Comment: Great. Thank you so much :)

Comment: I thought of this procedure as solution but i was not able to get the syntax right. This is helpful